# Angular Forms: Submit Button with HostListener on 'click'

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a reactive Angular form in which I am using a button of `type="submit"` in order to submit the form context.
Now I want to make further actions by adding a directive to the button. In the `directive` I am using using `@HostListener('click'])` to do some stuff... 
My current problem is that the `HostListener` prevents the form-submit-event from being propergated to the form.
How do can I force the HostListener to propergate the submit event to the form?

Comment: In this demo both submit and hostlistener are fired: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3wrqk7?file=app%2FmyDirective.directive.ts. Could you explain or make changes to see your issue?

Comment: You are right... I used the HostListener to temporarily disable the button so it won't fire twice and this seems to be the problem, by disabling the button the event propagation is canceled as well

Comment: I suppose you want to delay the submit until directive has finished?

Comment: I have 2 situation a simple delay for some ms. to prevent double clicks and a callback situation for e.g. api-request... I could solve the problem by doing this:  setTimeout(() => {
      this.disabled = true;
    }); thereby the event will still be propergated and the button is disabled after the minimum browser timeout

Comment: So it's solved? :)

Comment: Yes! delaying the the disable action by a minimal amount solved the problem